# How to use AWX inventory from survey?

Tags: ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I want to use dynamic host inventory that needs to be filled by the executor from the survey. How can I implement this feature?

Comment: I have 12 sets of inventory groups and its facts from aws, so all the operations are the same and we need to perform the specified task only on the selected inventory group. Instead of writing separate workflow and job templates, how can I achieve this>\?

Comment: I also have the same question. Does AWX support this (pass variable value from survey to the dynaminc inventory file used by the template)?